# Rest webservice sends JSON date format in request, and I need to validate if this date is past date or not

Tags: java, datetime, validation, java-8, datetime-comparison

Request:

```
{"start date":"2025-01-15T00:00:01.000z"}
```

Java code to validate this date is past date or not.

Comment: This is functionality available is core Java Framework. Please read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `Instant.parse(requestBody.get("start date")).compareTo(Instant.now()) < 0`?

Comment: Is that `z` on the end actually uppercase `Z`?

Comment: @BasilBourque FWIW `Instant.parse()` accepts both lower case `z` and upper case `Z`.

Comment: Please don’t expect Stack Overflow to be a code writing service. Instead before you post a question here, search and research. If possible, try to write your code yourself. If it fails, show us how it fails and spell out what your search brought up. It will allow people here to help you much more precisely, You will learn considerably more. it will make more people more willing to help you.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant
.parse( "2025-01-15T00:00:01.000Z" ) 
.isBefore( Instant.now() )
```

## ISO 8601

You have text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end indicates the text represents a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

The `Z` should be uppercase. I assume your example has a typo with its lowercase `z`.

## `Instant`

Parse as a [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant startDate = Instant.parse( "2025-01-15T00:00:01.000Z" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean isPast = startDate.isBefore( now ) ;
```